# Javascript does not write innerHTML of element but flashes result?

Tags: javascript

In this simple program, the script does not write result `id="result"` just flashes the resultant value. Can anybody take a look and show why this behavior? What am I doing wrong?

```js
function multiplication() {
  var product,
    no1 = document.getElementById('no1').value,
    no2 = document.getElementById('no2').value;

  product = no1 * no2;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = product;
}

function division() {
  var divis,
    no1 = document.getElementById('no1').value,
    no2 = document.getElementById('no2').value;

  divis = no1 / no2;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = divis;
}
```

```html
 <h2>Write a JavaScript program to calculate multiplication and division of two numbers ?</h2>
<h3>Sample Form</h3>
<form name="sample" method="POST">
  1st Number:
  <input type="text" id="no1" name="firstno" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 2nd Number:
  <input type="text" id="no2" name="secondno" />
  <button id="mul" onclick="multiplication();">Multiply</button>
  <button id="div" onclick="division();">Division</button>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: yes, however, When I run it inside an HTML document, then problem shows. Can you plz, copy it in a new HTML document and test it ?

Comment: @j08691 — From the console: *Blocked form submission to '' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.* — Stack snippets are sandboxed in a way that prevents the problem from occuring.

Comment: The default type of the `<button>` element is `submit`, so you're submitting the form and not doing anything to suppress that. Just change it to `type=button`.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah I saw that after I posted the comment.

Comment: Just get rid of the Form element

Answer (score 2):

1. The submit button is clicked
2. The JavaScript runs
3. The form is submitted
4. A new page is loaded

The new page doesn't have the DOM changes that were on the old page.

Either prevent the default behaviour of the submit button or bind your event handler to a different kind of control.

Answer (score 2):

Your JS is working but when the user clicks a submit button the form is also submitted, because that's the default action.

Prevent the form from submitting.

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();" name="sample" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<h2>Write a JavaScript program to calculate multiplication and division of two numbers ?</h2>
<h3>Sample Form</h3>
<form name="sample" method="POST">
  1st Number:
  <input type="text" id="no1" name="firstno" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 2nd Number:
  <input type="text" id="no2" name="secondno" />
  
</form>
<button id="mul" onclick="multiplication();">Multiply</button>
  <button id="div" onclick="division();">Division</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Put the `button` tag outside the `form` tag.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" id="mul" onclick="multiplication();">Multiply</button>
<button  type="button" id="div" onclick="division();">Division</button>
```

This might help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form name="sample" method="POST">
1st Number:
<input type="text" id="no1" name="firstno" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 2nd Number:
<input type="text" id="no2" name="secondno" />
<button id="mul"  type="button" onclick="multiplication();">Multiply</button>
<button id="div" type="button" onclick="division();">Division</button>
```

```
function multiplication(event) {

var product,
  no1 = document.getElementById('no1').value,
  no2 = document.getElementById('no2').value;

product = no1 * no2;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = product;
 }

 function division(event) {

var divis,
  no1 = document.getElementById('no1').value,
  no2 = document.getElementById('no2').value;

divis = no1 / no2;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = divis;
```

}